# Implode array to format, then repackage as an array for return

Tags: php, arrays

```
/** 
 * Makes directories if they do not exist
 * 
 * @param array $dirs array of directories
 * @return bool if TRUE and error array if FALSE
 *
 */
function mkdir_if_not_exist($dirs) {
    $err = array();
    if (is_array($dirs)) {
        foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
            if (!is_dir($dir)) {
                if (!mkdir($dir)) {
                    $err[] = "Directory {$dir} could not be created.";
                }
            }
        }
        if (count($err) > 1) {
            $err = implode('<br>', $err);
            count($err) > 2 ? $err .= 'Check if you have permission to make folders on the server' : '';
            $err = explode($err);           
        }
    } else {
        trigger_error('Array is required for function ' . __FUNCTION__, E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    if (!empty($err)) {
        // return errory array
        return $err;
    } else {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

This is a simple function I wrote to take an array of directories and check if they exist, if not then create them, and if there is an issue in creating them add an err. If there is more than one directory that was 'unmakeable' I want to be able to add a line break between values, and if there is more than 2 errors I want to add an additional message. and repackage it as an array. I keep getting errors, and I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I plan on accessing it in the following fashion:

```
$dir = array('this', 'that');
$out = mkdir_if_not_exist($dir);
if (is_bool($out)) {
  echo 'success'
} else {
  // output array
  echo implode('', $out);
}
```

UPDATE:

```
    if (count($err) > 1) {
        $err = implode('<br>', $err);
        $err = explode('<br>', $err);
        $err = array_push($err, 'Check if you have permission to make folders on the server');
    }
```

Comment: why don't you use try - catch to find out which errors? Do you know more about the errors, so that we can help you better? If you are using linux: do you have also the permission to make directories in the directories above the level you want to create them in?

Comment: explode($err);  is not a  correct call. What kind of error you are getting ?

Comment: The issue now is `array_push` is for some reason not working...

Answer (score 0):

why not use [mkdir(dirname, premissons, recursive)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php)

sorry i've misterunderstood - your [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) is missing argument.

remove implode and explode in mkdir_...() and implode array on echo

```PHP
if (count($err) > 2)
    $err[] = 'Check if you have permission to make folders on the server';
```

Comment: Directories are not nested. And I want to handle the creation of an array of directories or multiple directories at once (if they do not exist) to prevent script errors down the raod.

Answer (score -1):

One problem I see right away is that you are doing `count($err) > 2 ?` right after you just assigned $err a string value as a result of the implode() function. If you meant to count if there were more than 2 errors that is not what you're getting. count() on a string will always return 1.

I really don't understand why you would want to implode $err into a string and then turn around and explode it back into an array in the first place. If the purpose of the function is to return an array of errors when there are problems, then it should be the role of the calling code to decide how to format the resulting error array to display to the user instead of trying to force formatting into the function itself.

But if you do want your html formatting in the data, I suppose it would be easier to just add 
 tags to the end of the errors as they are created:

```
$err[] = "Directory {$dir} could not be created.<br />";
```

Then instead of doing `if (count($err) > 1) {`, just do:

```
if (count($err) > 2) {
  $err[] = 'Check if you have permission to make folders on the server';          
}
```

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. But lets say I do want to format it before outputting, and add the 'check... blah blah' to the array

Comment: Added code to answer your question more directly. Of course you always end up with a <br /> in the errors, even if there is only one error.

Comment: Please lookup the return value of array_push() to see the new error you have created.